# accept more than FD_SETSIZE connection

Tags: c, linux

In linux and c enviroment is possible to write a server that "accept" on one o more ip address and work (recv/send) with more than FD_SETSIZE clients (sockets), using "select" (not poll). I probe with threads or with context but I have not found a solution. Exist a solution ?

Comment: Perhaps doing some research about [the C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) could help you?

Comment: And please refrain from using both the C and C++ tags, use only the tag of the language you actually program in.

Comment: @MarioRollino: What exact application do you have in mind? With how many users and how much data? Please **edit your question** to tell a lot more (so add several paragraphs) and motivate it.

Comment: If `poll` and `epoll` is not acceptable, you can try to increase the definition of `FD_SETSIZE` (and `__FD_SETSIZE` and  maybe other related defs) in linux headers and recompile linux kernel.

Comment: I can not use poll, i must use select. I think for more thread that accept on more ports, and/or change the context (setcontext/swapcontex) ... any idea ?

Comment: @MarioRollino: Please *edit your question* to explain why you cannot use `poll`  (which is really strange) and why you believe that using a lot more threads is worthwhile. Explain what application you want to code, why you really need to use `select` (and what does that mean on systems where `select` is *emulated* by `poll`), and how many connections (and data volume, bandwidth, HTTP requests per second, sessions) do you have in mind. You still need to **improve *a lot* your question**. And please *don't comment your question* but edit it. Leave comments to others!

Comment: @MarioRollino: What would happen to you when `select` is unavailable, or don't work as wanted on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of the old [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), since `FD_SETSIZE` is a compile-time constant.

<sup>(increasing `FD_SETSIZE` is unreasonable: you would need to recompile the kernel, probably the C library and all libraries using `select` - practically speaking that could almost mean rebuilding your distribution from source -, and you certainly would need to dive into implementation details you really don't want to care about; and that is one of treasons why `select` should be avoided; `poll` can handle more file descriptors, and more importantly can handle a small set of file descriptors some of which have big numerical values, which would be essential in most multi-threading approaches)</sup>

Read also about the [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) (as commented by [Some programming dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)). If you have that much connections, you should design your program with care, have a lot of RAM. Consider using some *existing* event loop library ([libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/), ...), look into [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (HTTP client library), [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (HTTP server library). Or design your application as some [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) one (above some *existing* web server). Or design it as some internal  HTTP server (running on *several* machines) connected to some [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing))  HTTP proxy, etc... Or use a (or several) database systems (perhaps [distributed databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database)).

I would recommend to **stay pragmatical** if you are coding a new application. Code it carefully, but with limited scaling in mind. When (and only if) you have millions of users and many dozens of thousands of simultaneous connections you would get funding to redesign it for such a large scale (and you'll need to spend a lot on hardware too). And at that large scale `FD_SETSIZE` is only a *tiny* problem (you'll have a lot of other issues).

If you need to address C10k (or C100K) today, be sure to get enough developer man power for that -you may need a team of qualified developers working for at least one year.

> but I have not found a solution.

Because with your constraints there might be none.

---

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (freely downloadable, a bit old) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). To learn about multi-threading, read some good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Avoid having lots of threads (you probably want at most a few dozen of them on a powerful machine).

<sup>You should **improve your question** to motivate it and give your context and the real issues you are tackling. Your "I must use select" motto smells badly like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If using `select` is so essential, accept the limitations it has: maximal fd is 1024 (the value of `FD_SETSIZE`), so speak to your manager or client about that limitation. If *you* choose to use `select`, that was a design mistake and you need to work on refactoring your code.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`FD_SETSIZE` could on some systems be redefined before including anything and `select` would use that set size. This has never been standardised though and may not work on certain systems. It's also dangerous since you need to be very sure that the correct define was used everywhere which could be harder than it looks.

There is no portable way of doing it and this is why no new code should use `select`. `poll` has existed for decades as a replacement for `select` specifically because it solves this and other problems that select has. Don't use `select`, it's a very bad interface.

For higher throughput daemons, you should probably even avoid `poll` and use one of the less portable interfaces like `kqueue` or `epoll`, or even better use a library that wraps those for you like libevent or libev or such.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `select()`, if that means non-blocking mode and selecting for every channel. Blocking mode with a thread per connection doesn't rely on FD_SETSIZE at all, and neither does asynchronous I/O.